# MUI V5 - MakeStyles style gets overwritten

Tags: material-ui

I just updated to **5.0.0-alpha.25** (coming from 5.0.0-alpha.10) and now makeStyles is not working. I could not find anything in the breaking changes related to it so I wonder if it is a bug. When inspecting an element the makeStyles css rule is overwritten by a strange called css rule which seems to be the default values.

Here is an image which shows the rules in the inspector

[image: Inspector]

Did anyone face the same issue or am I overseeing a change in the makeStyles usage.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
        paddingRight: theme.spacing(2),
        display: 'contents'
    },
    row: {
        backgroundColor: "red"
    }
}));

/* ... */

const classes = useStyles()

/* ... */

<Grid container spacing={1} className={classes.root} alignItems="flex-start" justifyContent="center">
```

Comment: I also have such a problem. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I think adding a `injectFirst` to the `<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>` fixed the problem for me

Comment: how to use that component, I added button problem is not fixed

Comment: You need to wrap your components with the `StyledEngineProvider`. I would suggest your index.js file for that because it is the highest in the hierarchy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. You need to wrap your entire application in StyledEngineProvider component. I've done this in index.js file. Restart you local server by npm start nad works perfectly

Here's example

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import StyledEngineProvider from '@mui/material/StyledEngineProvider'

ReactDOM.render( <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst> <App /> </StyledEngineProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```